# Set line alpha when plotting multiple roc curves (in same color) with plotROC

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I'm ploting my ROC curves with plotROC. Below is the example code. I need to plot multiple roc curves with the same color. I found I need to use `alpha` in `aes`.  Now I need to control the transparency of my curves. Using `alpha` in `geom_roc` is not working. Does anyone knows what I can do? Thanks a lot.

```
D.ex <- rbinom(50, 1, .5)
rocdata <- data.frame(D = c(D.ex, D.ex), 
                   M = c(rnorm(50, mean = D.ex, sd = .4), 
                         rnorm(50, mean = D.ex, sd = 1)), 
                   Z = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), each=20) )
library(plotROC)
ggplot(rocdata, aes(m=M, d=D, alpha=Z)) + 
            geom_roc(cutoffs.at = NULL, n.cuts=0, color='blue')+
            theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `plotROC::geom_rec` you have to set `alpha` with `linealpha` argument (not within `aes`). But for this to work you also need to specify line group. Usually in `ggplot2` it's done with `group = Z`, but in `geom_rec` it doesn't work. Quick solution would be to set color by `Z` (`color = Z`) and with `scale_color_manual` set same color.

```
library(plotROC)
ggplot(rocdata, aes(m = M, d = D, color = Z)) + 
    geom_roc(cutoffs.at = NULL, n.cuts = 0, linealpha = 0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = rep("black", length(unique(rocdata$Z)))) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]